# Planning on Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a table named "Motorbike" with as fields (matriculation', 'number_motorbike', 'status').

I have another table named "Revision" with as fields ('date_revision_start', 'date_revision_end', 'garage', 'fk_motorbike').

The goal is that if the motorbike is under revision, it must be unavailable (automatically)...

it works almost ! So, the modificaiton of the status for the motorbike changes automatically only for the date "today"

[image]

[image]

But, for the date from 02/08/2019 to 06/08/2019 I have a problem. When, we will be, on 02/08/2019 or 06/08/2019 the status of the motorbike is always available... **Normally, it must be unavailable.**

Can you help me solve this problem?

```
$motorbikes = Motorbike::oldest()->paginate(5);
$revisionId = Revision::where('date_revision_start', "<=" , Carbon::now())->where('date_revision_end', ">=", Carbon::now())->pluck('fk_motorbike')->toArray();
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you are asking, and if you are having trouble with the query not producing the right dates, I can see that you are very close.

If your dates in your **model** are set as `dates`:

```
protected $dates = [
    'date_revision_start',
    'date_revision_end'
];
```

I suggest you use the `whereDate` method to pull the query.  So, something like this:

```
$now = Carbon::now();
$revisionId = Revision::whereDate('date_revision_start', "<=" , $now)->whereDate('date_revision_end', ">=", $now)->pluck('fk_motorbike')->toArray();
```

The query builder method `whereDate` should work well to give you a good match for the bikes that are down for revision (into the variable `$revisionId`).  Hopefully this will help.

Comment: Thanks so I have to wait , tomorrow to see if it works? ^^
The motorbike AAA001 from  30/08/2019 to 31/08/2019 be available automatically on 02/09/2019 for example?

Comment: Hehe, not necessarily.  You can try to manipulate the `$now` variable into something like `Carbon::tomorrow()` or any other date to test it out.  IE cheat the now part and test with different dates to see if it works.  Or add a week to see if the AAA001 bike is no longer in revision next week: `$now= Carbon::now()->addWeek();`

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my message, my problem is solved thanks to you. :-) You think that if I add a date from 01/01/2019 to 04/01/2019 for the bike AAA0001 and then I always add for the same bike 02/01/2019 to 03/01/2019 I Can have a validation system that says it's already "unavailable"?

Comment: Yes, I think so.  I think this can be done with very similar code to what we have here.  I think the easiest way to do this would be to validate by taking the second bike's input dates independently and comparing with two queries replacing `$now` with the second bike start date and then replacing `$now` with the second bike end date.  Play around with it, but I think you can do this with very similar code to above.  You'll also need to check to see if the bike's FK is the same as the one that is down for revision.

Comment: OK, I'll try that tomorrow morning. Thank you very much for your help. I wish you an excellent night.